# SelectList does not select correct value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently having some issues with getting my `SelectList` to default to a defined initial value. I created a snippet to demonstrate the issue: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ozroT1

Essentially I want my DropDownList to display `[null,1,2,3,4,5]` which will map to `Model.ChosenNumber`.

The model I have for this looks is represented by this simplified version:

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public int? ChosenNumber;
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PickList;
}
```

I create a `List<SelectListItem>` like so:

```
List<SelectListItem> pickNumberList = new List<SelectListItem>();
pickNumberList.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select( l => new SelectListItem { Text = l.ToString(), Value = l.ToString() }));
pickNumberList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = "-1" });
```

and then populate the model:

```
SampleViewModel model = new SampleViewModel();
model.ChosenNumber = 3;
model.PickList = new SelectList(pickNumberList, "Value", "Text");
return View(model);
```

Then finally in razor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ChosenNumber, Model.PickList)
```

Why doesn't the drop down list default to the `ChosenNumber \\(3)` ?

Comment: Not related but creating a 2nd identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one is pointless. It's just `model.PickList = pickNumberList;`

Comment: And you need to show your model in the question. The reason is that `ChosenNumber` is a field, not a property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've added the model to the question, however can you please elaborate on the last sentence in the above comment

Comment: Not sure why the close vote when I have provided a *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example* ?

Comment: Make it `public int? ChosenNumber { get; set; }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option is not selected because `ChosenNumber` is a field, not a property. Change it to

```
public int? ChosenNumber { get; set; }
```

In addition you do not need to create a 2nd identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one. It can be just

```
model.PickList = pickNumberList;
```

Comment: It would be better if you explained why a property is needed, +1 though

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto. Binding simply does not work with fields (and similarly, if an option was selected, the value would still be `null` in the POST method because the `DefaultModelBinder` ignores fields).

Comment: Yeah, I know, but the OP obviously doesn't :) that's why the comment